# nls convergence message in R

Tags: r, message, nls, convergence

I am looking for a definition of the convergence messages from `nls` in `R`. In particular, what is the difference between `relative convergence (4)` and `both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out the source of `nls`, `nlminb`, `optimx`, and others using the PORT algorithm you'll see it references the PORT Fortran documentation for these convergence codes.

The documentation of `optimx` is even so good as to provide a URL. Like the URL on the webpage for the Fortran library, it is unfortunately broken.

This didn't dissuade me. I tried the link on the good 'ole WayBack Machine (Internet Archive) and found where the .pdf documentation was scraped in 2007:

https://web.archive.org/web/20070203144320/http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cstr/153.pdf

The "Favorable Returns" codes on page 4 go into a more detail than in R and additional details are available throughout the document. I believe this should answer your question.

[image]